# Type checking of function assignment, functions with union types arguments

Tags: typescript

This line produces error "Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'"

```
const myVar: string = "test" as number | string;  // error, fine
```

So why there is no error for this one?

```
const myFunc: (ns: number | string) => void = (n: number) => alert(n * 2);  // no error ???
```

Callbacks are used quite often in js/ts, so it seem strange to me.
Current ts version is 3.1

Comment: sure your functions shouldn't be const myFunc: (ns: number) => void = (n: number | string) => alert(+n * 2);  // no error ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under default compiler settings, callbacks are bi-variant, meaning that if the implementation parameter is a subtype of the declaration parameter the assignment is allowed.

This is obviously a big hole in the type system which was plugged with a `strict*` option, namely `strictFunctionTypes` as described in this [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654). If you enable this compiler option, your assignment will be an error.